# Can you style an active form input's label with just CSS

Tags: html, css

Given the following html

```
<label for="inputelement">label</label>
<input type="text" id="inputelement" name="inputelement" />
```

You can style the input on focus using

```
input:focus { background: green; }
```

Is there a way of also styling the `<label />` without JavaScript?

Thanks all

Comment: You can give the label an id or class and target it in your css. Or are you asking if you can style it without changing the markup and adding an id or class?

Comment: It can be done if you target browsers that support flexbox - see new answer below

Answer (score 39, accepted):

No. there is unfortunately no predecessor selector in css

```
input:focus -+ label { ... }
```

would be lovely.

having the label after the input would be dooable:

```
input:focus + label { ... }
```

you could use some positioning to display before...

Comment: thanks, i thought this might be the case. would be really nice. unfortunately i can't change the markup :o( i'll keep this in mind for the future though.

Comment: It can be done if you target browsers that support flexbox - see new answer below

Answer (score 27):

For completeness, if your input field is **within the label** you can use [focus-within](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within):

HTML:

```
<label>
   <input name="example" type="text">
</label>
```

CSS:

```
label:focus-within {
   background: #DEF;
}
```

Comment: Only FYI, IE doesn't support it https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-focus-within

Comment: This should be the selected answer, simple and works perfectly.

Comment: @alexbooots No this shoudn't be. Implicit Label aren't recommended. Here is [a small article](https://css-tricks.com/html-inputs-and-labels-a-love-story/#:~:text=There%20are%20two%20ways%20to,to%20the%20input%20(explicit).) you can read

Answer (score 10):

**UPDATED**

Make sure you check the draft as this may change: https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relational

The :has() relational pseudo-class will allow the selection of parents for example, the following selector matches only `<a>` elements that contain an  `<img>` child:

```
a:has(> img)
```

This can be combined with other selectors such as `:focus`, `:active` or `:not` to offer a lot of potential.

Unfortunately browser support isn’t great at the time of writing: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-has

<strike>Adding this for people finding this page in the **future**. CSS4 will have a parent selector allowing you to choose what element to apply the style to:</strike>

I think the current spec allows you to specify which item is matched with a ! sign - the subject selector.

```
label! > input {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

This allows far greater control than just parent, for example in this scary chain below the p tag is the target!

```
article > h1 + section > p! > b > a {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

Comment: ^ THIS. No support as of 2013, but eventually this is likely to become the correct way of doing this.

Comment: It looks like it has dissapeared from the draft. The solution according the current draft will be using :has selector. Instead of "! >b > a", it would be ":has( >b >a)"

Comment: @Blauhirn I have updated my answer to reflect the changes to the spec since first writing it

Comment: 2021 and we're still dealing with it.

Comment: fortunately it appears that there is at least recent activity on its implementation in the Chromium project https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=669058

Answer (score 8):

You can use an attribute selector:

```
label[for=inputelement]:focus,
label[for=inputelement]:active {
    /*styles here*/
}
```

Note that this isn't supported by IE6, but should work in all other browsers, including IE7 and IE8.

That will obviously only work for that specific ID. If you would like it to work for *all* IDs, simply leave out the ID:

```
label[for]:focus,
label[for]:active {
    /*styles here*/
}
```

This will now work for all labels with a `for` attribute.

If you need something in between, you'll need to use classes.

Comment: But this wouldn't respond to the `:focus`, or `:active` pseudo states.

Comment: It can't be that prescribed unfortunately aswell, it needs to work for any id/name etc

Comment: @David Thomas - fair enough, so add :focus and :active to the selector.... I'll edit it in my answer....

Comment: @Dave Taylor - you can specify an attribute selector with or without a value; I wasn't sure what you needed. I'll edit my answer to include that info.

Comment: this code is still only targeting the label and has nothing to do with whether its associated input has received focus.

Comment: @Spudley - very keen to see a working demo of this with the original questionn posters markup as html

Answer (score 7):

You can, so long as the `label` follows the `input` in the Mark-up:

```
input:focus + label,
input:active + label {
    /* style */
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Okay the idea is to wrap the input, label, help, error etc. in a Flexbox Container.
Then use the `+` selector, to select the label element.
Note: it will work only when `<label>` comes after `<input>`
Then you define the `<label>` order by using the flexitem `order` property.
Sure you can also using classnames.

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
input {
    border: none;
}
label {
    order: -1;
}
input:focus {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
input:focus + label{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <input id="username" />
    <label for="username">Username</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, of course you can.

You'll need to:

- Group both label and the form into a parent element (like a div)
- Style the label with focus pseudo selector selector for the parent, ie `.parent:focus label { color: green }`

You can see a very minimal sample at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q06xjnf7/) I made.

```html
<div class='workarea'>
    <div class='hasinput'>
        <label>Label 1 (should be green when active)</label>
        <input />
    </div>
    <div class='hasinput'>
        <label>Label 2 (should be green when active)</label>
        <input />
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.workarea {
    max-width: 500px;
}

label,
input {
    width: 100%;
}

.hasinput {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.hasinput label {
    color: blue;
}

.hasinput:focus-within label {
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: Nice, I hadn't stumbled across  ```:focus-within``` before. And it's well supported too:   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within

Answer (score 1):

Give your input button a style class

css style:

```
INPUT.book:hover, INPUT.book:focus:hover {
    background-image:url(book_over.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height: 40px;
    width: 140px;
    font-family:calibri, Tahoma;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}

INPUT.book {
    background-image:url(book_active.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height: 40px;
    width: 140px;
    font-family:calibri, Tahoma;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

and the input html:

```
<input name="Bestil2" type="submit" class="book"  value="Book møde" />
```

I haven't figured out yet, how to avoid grey background even though I have a transparent png file, maybe just an jpg will do. But I hope this helps.
Good luck :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative usign CSS grid:

As some sugested if the label is after the input then using flex or in my case using CSS grid you can place the label first.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.form-field {
  display: grid;
  gap: 4px;
}

.form-field label {
  grid-row: 1;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #737373;
}

.form-field input {
  outline: unset;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 1px solid #737373;
}

.form-field input:focus {
  border-color: #328dd2;
}

.form-field input:focus + label {
  color: #328dd2;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-field">
  <input id="myinput" />
  <label for="myinput">
    My Input
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done if you target browsers that support flexbox - see this: http://plnkr.co/edit/g376cf38iphfvGfSubOz?p=preview

For brevity, the css there is minimal but you'll need some browser specific prefixes to extend support to somewhat older browsers.

Comment: I don't see how *flexbox* would make any difference. Code is ok, but focus styling works even without ```display: flex```.

Comment: @Kamafeather: here is a longer explanation: the solution uses adjacent siblings selector (+) which means <label> must come AFTER <input> in the html.  Flexbox is used to modify the order in which the html elements are presented.

Comment: Please use snipplets, the link you wroted it's 404

Comment: Now it works. The other day didn't. Please change the answer including your code in a snipplet, because plnkr can delete your code or disappear; the snipplet of Stackoverflow will remain always here.

Comment: I must refrain from upvoting since the answer is hidden behind a link.